# I want to know how to add to digits together in a list. Say the number is 10. I need it to add 1 + 0 to the new list

Tags: python

I want to know how to add to digits together in a list. Say the number is 10. I need it to add 1 + 0 to the new list. If the item in the list is 11 it needs to add 2 to the list

```
def main():
    #Define List
    mylist = [4,5,5,2,7,2,0,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    print(mylist)
    newlist = []
    for each in mylist:
        if (each % 2 == 0):
            newlist.append(each)
        else:
            newlist.append(each + each)
        for each in newlist:
            if each >= 10:
                newlist.append(each + each)

    print(newlist)

main()
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

To get the digit sum of a number, you should convert the number to a string, loop over the string, and add all chars together (after converting them to int again):

```
def get_digit_sum(num):
    return sum(int(x) for x in str(num))
```

To do this for a list of numbers, you should use list comprehension:

```
>>my_nums = [11, 22, 56, 345]
>>digit_sums = [get_digit_sum(x) for x in my_nums]
>>print(digit_sums)
[2, 4, 11, 12]
```

This is also possible to do in one expression:

```
>>my_nums = [11, 22, 56, 345]
>>digit_sums = [sum(int(x) for x in str(num)) for num in my_nums]
```

As per abarnet's comment, you may want the number `345` to be converted to `3+4+5=12`, and the convert `12` to `1+2=3`. This can be done using recursion. By using a `max_digits` parameter, you can specify the maximum number of digits in the returned number.

```
def get_digit_sum(num, max_digits=1):
    d = sum(int(x) for x in str(num))
    if len(str(d)) > max_digits:
        return get_digit_sum(d)
    return d
```

or a bit shorter:

```
def get_digit_sum(num, max_digits=1):
    d = sum(int(x) for x in str(num))
    return get_digit_sum(d) if len(str(d)) > max_digits else d
```

Both of the above functions would then yield:

```
>>my_nums = [11, 22, 56, 345]
>>print [get_digit_sum(x) for x in my_nums]
[2, 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Great answer. And if the OP wants `345` to turn in `3` instead of `12`, it's simple to turn your `get_digit_sum` into a recursive function that goes until `len(str(num))<2`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is trying to do a little bit more than what you describe - in particular, you *double* any odd numbers. Because you're doing two things to each number (possibly double, sum the digits), you don't want to put it in the list until *both* steps are done. Instead do something like this:

```
for each in mylist:
    if each % 2 != 0:
        each *= 2
    if each >= 10:
        each = # sum of digits
    newlist.append(each)
```

There's a couple of ways you could sum the digits. You can use `divmod` to get the quotient and the remainder of the number divided by 10 - the remainder is the units column, the quotient is every column to the left of that:

```
if each >= 10:
    q, r = divmod(each, 10)
    each = q + r
```

the other way is to get the string representation, which lets you iterate over every digit, convert it *back* to a number and add them:

```
if each >= 10:
   each = sum(int(d) for d in str(each))
```

this is possibly easier to understand It *is*, however, a fair bit slower - which might matter if you have a very large amount of input.

These two approaches do work differently if you end up with any three or more digit numbers in the list - for 110, the divmod version will do 11 + 0 = 11, while the string version will do 1 + 1 + 0 = 2.

Also note that *neither* is guaranteed to end up with a single-digit number in the end - for 99, both of these will give you 18. If you want that further reduced to 9, you can change the `if` to a loop:

```
while each >= 10:
   each = sum(int(d) for d in str(each))
```

to do this for the divmod version, you could put it into a recursive function instead:

```
def digit_sum(number):
    q, r = divmod(number, 10)
    if q > 10:
       q = digit_sum(q)
    return q+r
```

Making the same change to the `divmod` version as the string version *appears* to give the same answer in every case I've tried, but I have no idea if this is guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: Nice explanation. But a simple loop (or recursive function) around `divmod` will solve the `110` problem—assuming it's a problem—even in the non-repeated-sum case.

Answer (score 0):

```
> [int(d) for d in str(123)]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

A function that sums the digits for a given number:

```
def sum_of_digits(num):
    return sum([int(x) for x in str(num)])
```

And a list comprehension to apply it to the entire list:

```
newlist=[sum_of_digits(number) for number in mylist]
```

Comment: The OP appears to be using Python 3.x, so your `newlist` won't be a list, just an iterator.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to build the list of digits just to mass to `sum`; just use a genexpr.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know what you are going for. If the value is even and less than 10 add it to the new list, if the value is odd then double it and if that is less than 10 add it to the new list. Now if the value is greater than 10 then take the sum of all the digits and add it to the list.

I am sure there is a better way to do this, but this is what I came up with.

```
list = [4,5,5,2,7,2,0,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
newlist = []
for i in list:
    if i % 2 == 0 and len(str(i)) > 1:
        newlist.append(sum([int(x) for x in str(i)]))
    elif i % 2 == 0:
        newlist.append(i)
    elif len(str(i*2)) > 1:
        newlist.append(sum([int(x) for x in str(i*2)]))
    else:
        newlist.append(i*2)

print newlist

input:   [4, 5, 5, 2, 7, 2, 0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
outcome: [4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 0, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 1, 6, 5, 8]
```